# Separate scripts with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I recently worked on a web app, and i wanted to separate it into modules.
I searched and found out that RequireJs is the best for this. I read the doc, and some tutorials about it and came up with this

```
    requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "js/lib",
    shim: {
        'jquery-1.12.1.min': ['jquery-1.12.1.min'],
        'materialize.min': ['materialize.min'],
        'knockout-3.4.0': ['knockout-3.4.0'],
        'pouchdb-5.3.0.min': ['pouchdb-5.3.0.min']
    },
    waitSeconds: 0,
    paths: {
        'jquery-1.12.1.min': 'jquery-1.12.1.min',
        'materialize.min': 'materialize.min',
        'knockout-3.4.0': 'knockout-3.4.0',
        'pouchdb-5.3.0.min': 'pouchdb-5.3.0.min',
    }   
});
require(["jquery-1.12.1.min", "knockout-3.4.0", "materialize.min", "pouchdb-5.3.0.min"], function($, ko) { //My main functions and other stuff ... }
```

My index has the following:

`<script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/converter.js"></script>`

But it seems that my `Jquery`, `KO`, `materialize.css` and `pouchdb`  aren't loading as i see on my chrome dev tools in Network:

[image: chrome dev screen Network]

I also read about the shim config how to set up the dependences and i want them in that order. I don't really know what am i missing, any help would really be appreciated.

**Folder structure** is:

```
js:  
   lib:
     ->jquery-1.12.1.min.js
     ->knockout-3.4.0.js
     ->pouchdb-5.3.0.min.js
     ->materialize.min.js 
     ->require.js 
   main.js
   converter.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems require and materialze.css have a problem with hammer.js, what i recommend is you go and download [Hammer.min.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) and include it in your lib folder.
Then in your main.js add the following:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    waitSeconds: 0,
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        jquery: 'jquery-1.12.1.min',
        materialize: 'materialize.min',
        knockout: 'knockout-3.4.0',
        pouchdb: 'pouchdb-5.3.0.min',
        hammer: 'hammer.min'
    },
    shim: {
        hammer: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        pouchdb: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        knockout: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'ko'
        },
        materialize: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'hammer'],
        },
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});
```

You include you hammer and also the dependency for jquery on it. And i see that you didn't put the PouchDb object in the function:

`define(["jquery", "knockout", "pouchdb", "materialize" ], function($, ko, PouchDB) {...`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much, i absolutely forgot PouchDb object, also for the provided code, works fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [path](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths), requirejs replace module id prefixes (name in config) with the corresponding value.

Using [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) you can export a global variable and configure the dependencies ( materialize depends jquery so you have to import jQuery before importing materialize.js )

```
    requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "js/lib",
    waitSeconds: 0,
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery-1.12.1.min',
        'materialize': 'materialize.min',
        'knockout': 'knockout-3.4.0',
        'pouchdb': 'pouchdb-5.3.0.min',
        'hammer': 'hammer.min',
    },
    shim: {
        pouchdb: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        knockout: {
            exports: 'ko'
        },
        materialize: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'hammer']
        },
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});

require(["jquery", "knockout", "materialize", "pouchdb"], function ($, ko) {
    console.log($);
    console.log(ko);
});
```

Comment: Ok i used the code you provided and addedd the dependecy for others: `baseUrl: "js/lib",
    waitSeconds: 0,
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery-1.12.1.min',
        'materialize': 'materialize.min',
        'knockout': 'knockout-3.4.0',
        'pouchdb': 'pouchdb-5.3.0.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'pouchdb': {
            deps: ['knockout']
        },
        'knockout': {
            deps: ['materialize']
        },
        'materialize': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        }
    }` but i get an error:404 hammer.js(not found)

Comment: i added hammer in the sample. Knockout does not depend on materialize.

Comment: Still 404 for Hammer.min :/

Comment: Did you remove the dependencies between knockout and materialize? I made a test and all the libs are downloaded.

Comment: The problem is i get 404 for hammer.js, should i download it and include in my folder, or what to do with it ? Why is it showing ?

Comment: i have the following: 
`pouchdb: {
            deps: ['jquery','knockout']
        },
        knockout: {
            exports: 'ko'
        },
        materialize: {
            deps: ['jquery','hammer']
        },
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        }`

Comment: pouchdb does not depend on knockout, you have to remove it. You have to add the hammer.min in your js/lib folder  because it's declared as a dependency for materialize.